# Javascript - On android, how to close google chrome browser window?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

On Android i have Google chrome browser window open from my Java app. On that page i have following javascript to close the browser window so that it can go back to my Java app.

```
function die() {
  //window.close();  ------ FAIL
  //window.history.back();  ------ FAIL
  //open(location, '_self').close();   ------ FAIL
  $('body').html('<h1>Session closed, i cant help you to close via JavaScript it sucks. Press the back button manually. Yes it stupid but thats the only way?</h1>');
  return false;
}
```

But above window.close or other options are not working. How do i close the browser window in such case?

Comment: Did you try simple with Back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your app to launch a [Chrome custom tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).  When this single tab-in-a-window closes it will return to your application.